# How to apply .h1, .h2, ... styles to form fields?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm building a kind-of-CMS app where user can set a page title. I try to be as WYSIWYG as possible, so to display my title field, I want to apply the final title's style.

The title will be displayed using:

```
<div class="h1">My gorgeous title</div>
```

But it looks like `.form-control` class enforces both alignment and font size: putting `h1` as a field class doesn't help (you can check the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g9bdompz/2/)): if I remove it, `h1` applies but alignment no more.

Is there a trick to enforce another font-size without changing the alignment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CSS, styles for an `id` will always trump styles for a `class`.

What you're seeing is the styles for `#textinput2` (inherited from `body`, I think) trumping the styles for `.h1`.

Your solution is to specify style rules for an element which has both an `id` of `#textinput2` and *simultaneously* a `class` of `.h1`.

Then you will get the result you are after:

```
#textinput2.h1 {
font-size: 36px;
line-height: 48px;
height: 48px;
}
```

## =====

**Alternative (more generic) solution**

```
input[value~='.h1'] {
font-size: 36px;
line-height: 48px;
height: 48px;
}
```

This CSS will apply the styles to any `input` element in which the `value` attribute contains the word `.h1`. (You can adapt the *trigger word*, as needed).

Comment: Will wait for another answer to maybe find a nicer solution (I don't actually know what's inside the h1 class as it is generated using the less file, so I would prefer an arbitrary solution). Else I'll assume yours! Thank you for your answer.

Comment: You know you can remove both the `class="h1"` from your HTML and the `.h1` from your CSS, right? Then you would simply have `#textinput2 {...}`

Comment: Better yet, I've added an alternative (more generic) solution to my post above, which pays no attention either to an element's `id` or `class` - it simply looks to see if the element has a `value` attribute and if the `value` attribute contains the word `.h1`.